# Can I add custom translations to Vuetify datepicker?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to implement new custom language in Vuetify, I want to translate vuetify datepicker months to my custom language. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to make up the month names yourself or do you want to use month names from a different language than the default? If the latter, can you check if the language you want to use is listed over here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/internationalization

Comment: Vuetify do not store months names in its `locale` source, as it do for interface "words". It uses JS Date object which supports BCP 47 language tag.

Comment: @JKL I want my custom language which is not supported by vuetify.

Comment: @bonusrk so there is no way to translate month names?

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers#date-pickers-internationalization

Comment: @MichalLevý this is only for built-in locales, not for custom.

Comment: What does "custom language" means exactly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [clearly stated in the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers#date-pickers-internationalization)

> The date picker supports internationalization through the JavaScript Date object. Specify a BCP 47 language tag using the `locale` prop, and then set the first day of the week with the `first-day-of-week` prop

Specifically it is using [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) to get localized month/date names. So the list of locales is not limited to the list of Vuetify localisations specified [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/internationalization) and depends on the browser.

If you need something really special, lets say Klingon, you can override methods used to format dates via props - specifically `month-format`, `header-date-format` and `title-date-format`

See both variants in [the demo](https://codepen.io/liwoj/pen/MWYVJxv?editors=1011)

Comment: Nice, demo really helped with those methods. Thanks